# Android Java Custom Input Field does not work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to create a custom input field on Android using java and xml.

Below the code does not show the hint and the most important error that when I write some text in the field and go to another page and come back again, it takes the text from the second field and write into the first and second input field.

Where am I wrong?

Thank for your response in advance.

Here is my custom input field xml file

mobpay_input_field.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:background="@drawable/background_cropped_drawable">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
            style="@style/MyStyle.InputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:hint="Test hint">

            <com.neste.app.views.CustomErrorEditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text"
                style="@style/InputBoxStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/InputBoxStyle"
                tools:text="Some error" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_clear_btn"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_small"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_small"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_m"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_cross"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/text_input_layout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/text_input_layout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_tip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_s"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_tiny"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_input_layout"
            tools:text="Some text"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</merge>
```

This is custom input field java file;
MobPayInputField.java

```
package com.neste.app.views;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;
import com.neste.app.R;
import com.neste.app.utils.AppUtils;

public class MobPayInputField extends FrameLayout {

    CharSequence text;
    CharSequence hint;
    CustomErrorEditText editText;
    TextView editTip;
    TextInputLayout inputLayout;
    int inputType;
    int maxLength;
    int textColor;
    boolean enabled;
    private View resetButton;

    public MobPayInputField(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public MobPayInputField(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public MobPayInputField(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs, R.styleable.MobPayInputField, 0, 0);
        hint = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.MobPayInputField_hint);
        text = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.MobPayInputField_text);
        textColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.MobPayInputField_textColor, 0);
        inputType = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.MobPayInputField_android_inputType, -1);
        enabled = typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.MobPayInputField_android_enabled, true);
        maxLength = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.MobPayInputField_maxLength, -1);

        typedArray.recycle();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobpay_input_field, this, true);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        editTip = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_tip);
        resetButton = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_clear_btn);
        inputLayout = findViewById(R.id.text_input_layout);

        if (text != null) {
            editText.setText(text);
        }

        if (hint != null) {
            inputLayout.setHint(hint);
        }

        if (inputType != -1) {
            editText.setInputType(inputType);
        }

        if (textColor != 0) {
            editText.setTextColor(textColor);
        }

        if (!enabled) {
            setEnabled(false);
            editText.setEnabled(false);
            editText.setFocusable(false);
            editText.setClickable(false);
            resetButton.setVisibility(GONE);
        }

        if (maxLength != -1) {

            // EditText does not support directly setting maxLength attribute but this
            // works as setting android:maxLength on the XML-layout
            editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
        }

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // empty on purpose
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // empty on purpose
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (enabled) {
                    resetButton.setVisibility(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString()) ?
                            VISIBLE : GONE);
                }
            }
        });
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(v -> editText.setText(""));

        forceLayout();
    }

    public void setOnEditorActionListener(TextView.OnEditorActionListener listener) {
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(listener);
    }

    public void setOnTextChangedListener(TextWatcher textWatcher) {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        editText.setText(text);
    }

    public void setTextColor(int color) {
        if (editText != null) {
            editText.setTextColor(color);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        super.setEnabled(enabled);
        this.enabled = enabled;
        resetButton.setVisibility(enabled && !TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText()) ?
                VISIBLE : GONE);
    }

    public void addNewFilter(InputFilter filter) {
        InputFilter[] currentFilters = editText.getFilters();
        InputFilter[] newFilters = new InputFilter[currentFilters.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(currentFilters, 0, newFilters, 0, currentFilters.length);
        newFilters[currentFilters.length] = filter;
        editText.setFilters(newFilters);
    }

    public void setFilters(InputFilter[] filters) {
        editText.setFilters(filters);
    }

    public void showError(boolean show) {

        // Set whitespace to also highlight the bottom line with error color
        showError(show, show ? " " : null);
    }

    public void showError(boolean show, int resId) {
        showError(show, getResources().getString(resId));
    }

    // if error string is null, show only icon
    public void showError(boolean show, String errorString) {
        inputLayout.setError(show && errorString != null ? errorString : null);
        editText.showError(show);
    }

    // Display tip below edit field
    public void setEditTextTip(String text) {
        editTip.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        editTip.setText(text);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return editText.toString();
    }

    public CharSequence getText() {
        return editText.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnFocusChangeListener(OnFocusChangeListener listener) {
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher textWatcher) {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    }

    public void onEditorAction(int imeActionDone) {
        editText.onEditorAction(imeActionDone);
    }

    public void requestTextFocus() {
        editText.requestFocus();
        AppUtils.showKeyboard(getContext(), editText);
    }

    public void setSelection(int length) {
        editText.setSelection(length);
    }

    public void allowOnlyNumbersAndSpaces() {
        editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789 _"));
    }
}
```

This is code inside attrs.xml file that defines attributes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="MobPayInputField">
        <attr name="textColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="maxLength" format="integer" />
        <attr name="hint" format="string" />
        <attr name="text" format="string" />
        <attr name="android:enabled" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="android:inputType" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And this is the login fragment that I implemented the custom input field
fragment_login.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/base_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_m"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".login.LoginActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/logo_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_l">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/login_neste_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/login_neste_height"
                android:src="@drawable/neste_logo" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/welcomeToNeste"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/neste_rounded_corner_drawable"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logo_container">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_m"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/login_email"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/login_email"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/login_email"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_user" />

            <com.neste.app.views.MobPayInputField
                android:id="@+id/login_email"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_m"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_xl"
                android:hint="@string/login_username_hint"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_m"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/password"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/password"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/password"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lock" />

            <com.neste.app.views.MobPayInputField
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_xl"
                android:hint="@string/login_password_hint"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/login_email" />

            <com.neste.app.views.ButtonWithLoadingView
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_xl"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/forgot_password_link"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/password"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/password"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/password"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/forgot_password_link"
                style="@style/Neste.TextAppearance.H3.Dim"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_xxl"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_xl"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_xxl"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_l"
                android:text="@string/password_forgot_link"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/email_sign_in_button" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <!-- BOTTOM CONTAINER -->

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/go_to_user_creation"
            style="@style/Neste.Button.Outline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_l"
            android:text="@string/registerButtonTitle" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/prod_switch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```